# How to move delete current line and move text to the top in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have the following code.

```
var post = new Post("abc",
   "def");
```

How do I move the whole second line to the above line which would result in this?

```
var post = new Post("abc", "def");
```

Comment: Have you tried `J`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like you want to join the two lines. The command to use, in normal mode, is <kbd>J</kbd> (capital/shifted letter/key.)